# Alternatives to abstract base class for storage

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, static-polymorphism

I'm wondering about the available alternatives to run-time polymorphism, specifically, an alternative to having a common base class between my classes in order to store and interact with instances of derived classes.
RTP has disadvantages of indirection through vtable look-up, and also forces the derived classes to be stored as pointers, and so generally they must be dynamically allocated. From what I've been told, this hinders inlining and compiler optimisations.

In short, I don't want this:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual void noise() const = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void noise() override const {std::cout<<"Woof!\n";};
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void noise() override const {std::cout<<"Meow!\n";};
};

//...

std::vector<Animal*> animals;
```

I want something like this:

```
class Dog
{
public:
    void noise() const {std::cout<<"Woof!\n";};
};

class Cat
{
public:
    void noise() const {std::cout<<"Meow!\n";};
};

//...

std::vector<*Things that have noise()*> animals;
```

Comment: see Sean Parents talk [Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil)

Comment: If you are going to ask questions like this, please produce examples that refer to your problem domain, not these idiotic Animal/Dog things.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. You can't have a `vector<T>` where `T` is not a fixed type. The best you could do is type erasure (see `std::function`), but that's no better in terms of polymorphic function dispatching, heap allocation, and so forth than a base class. The only real improvement is that it would manage its own memory. So long as the set of classes involved is not bounded (and therefore a `variant` isn't appropriate), you're going to have to pay for polymorphic dispatch. And it's not like `variant` visitation is free or something...

Comment: You mentioned inlining as a desired goal, and you presented an example of a vector of "things that have noise()". How do you see this working? Take on the role of the compiler. Assume the vector has been populated with something. You cannot know what that something is, but assume we already checked that it exists. How would you inline the expression `animals[0].noise()`? Or even evaluate that expression without some degree of indirection?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I can not help you, but for classes with data members, here is an optimization.

Let's suppose we want to create a bullet-hell game.

In a naive approach, we need a class `Bullet` :

```
class Bullet {
public:
    void draw(Renderer& r);
    virtual void update_logic(float delta);
    void run_physics();
protected:
    float vx, vy; //velocity
private:
    float x, y; //position
    //...
};
```

So, the `update_logic` method would be called to set the velocity of the bullet, then `run_physics` will apply this velocity to the position.

Modifying logic needs polymorphism, so your collection becomes `std::vector<Bullet*>` (or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bullet> >` in modern c++).

Then, in your main loop, first you update the logic, then the physics, then you draw your bullets.

Of course it is inefficient because of pointer dereference and vtables etc.

What you can do instead is :

```
class Bullet {
public:
    void draw(Renderer& r);
    void update_logic(float delta) { logic->update(delta); };
    void run_physics();
    void setVelocity(float, float);
    void setLogic(BulletLogic*);
private:
    float x, y, vx, vy;
    BulletLogic* logic;
};
```

So now, you can use `std::vector<Bullet>`, and the indirection will occure only when updating logic, but neither while running phyics or drawing the bullet.